# Loading DataTables - what's the best option?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin Datatables to show the projects/surveys/... from my mysql database. I'm working with Zend Framework to create my webapplication.
This is a preview from how it looks now:

[image]

This is my projectsAction in my LibrariesController. When you click on "SURVEYS/QUIZZES" you go to surveyAction in the same controller and the table reforms again in the view. A preview from how my table is formed in the view:

```
<table id="datatables" class="display">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php   $projects = $this->projects;
            foreach($projects as $project){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="project_click" id="<?= $project["Id"] ?>"><?= $project["Name"] ?></a></td>
                        <td class="buttons">
                            <?php
                            if($project["PermissionLevelId"] == 1){
                            ?>
                            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse"><a href="../projects/edit/projectid/<?= $project["Id"] ?>">EDIT</a></span>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse"><a href="../projects/use/projectid/<?= $project["Id"] ?>">USE</a></span>
                            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse"><a href="../projects/share/projectid/<?= $project["Id"] ?>">SHARE</a></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Is the best way to switch between projects / surveys / designs by going to a new action or should I load this with ajax calls?

I also have the problem when I click on for example "SURVEYS/QUIZZES" when I'm on the projects page and then when I'm on the surveys page I click on "PROJECTS" I get this:

[image]

The javascript didn't load ... . Can someone tell me what's the best solution in my case?

Comment: what do you mean when you say that the javascript didn't load? That you are not able to generate the dataTable? That you are not able to fill the dataTable with the new data? ...

Comment: The table is filled with the new data but as you can see the datatable didn't show fully. No searchbox, layout, ... . (in the second image)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that must change is the content of the table, not the structure, then it's gonna be better to use Ajax, and It is so easy to configure with dataTables.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to see your images, so it's difficult to figure it out.

I think that probably you are not initializing your dataTable. Add this on the header or in a method after update your data:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatables').dataTable();
  } );
</script>
```